# How to automate files upload?

Tags: workflow, file-upload

I have a folder on a shared drive that contains 10 .csv files. The files get updated everyday automatically. I need to upload this 10 files to my SP website everyday at 8AM. Is there any way I could create a workflow to do this ?

(PS I am not allowed to install SP server, so i cannot use Microsoft Visual Studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use visual studio and use the [SharePoint client object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537247%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to programmatically work with SharePoint without server admin privileges.

The 'least amount of effort' way to do this would be to use an open source tool like [Orbit One SP Bulk Document Importer](http://spbulkdocumentimport.codeplex.com/) and write a .bat file to kick off the process that you can run with Windows Task Scheduler.  The Orbit One tool uses the client object model.